# Two Worlds in Netlogo at the Same Time

Tags: simulation, netlogo, modeling

Good day,

We're trying to create something wherein we can visually have two simulations running at the same time in Netlogo. It will be divided into two halves,
The first half of the world will be simulating a run, and the other half will simulate another run with different variables.

is that possible?

I simply want to have my current program run on half of the screen.

Comment: Something like this http://ccl.northwestern.edu/modelsim/tools.shtml# -- "Two-world modeling" can't find the resource to this.

Comment: Why not just open up two copies of NetLogo?

Comment: Why not just run two NetLogos side by side?

Comment: cuz our leader doesn't want it that way lol. Aye, btw- is it possible for all turtles in a model to simply just occupy one half of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully at the image, you will see that it is actually a single `world` (in the NetLogo sense of the word - a specific type of output window) that has been visually separated with a grey wall down the middle. You can see this by looking at the top bar of the window - the normal panning controls and tick counter are at the left corner only and the 3D button is at the right corner only. That is, this has been constructed with clever coding rather than a NetLogo feature.

Assume you have turned the middle patches grey (eg `ask patches with [pxcor = 0][set pcolor grey]`) then the code for the left hand simulation would control agent movements so they have xcor < -0.5 and the right would use xcor > 0.5

Since you are running the same model with different parameter values, you will probably want the agents to be the same breed. They can have an attribute for whether left or right and use agentsets to construct the left turtles or the right turtles. But you might also want to consider having different breeds.

Here are some suggestions how to achieve the effect entirely within NetLogo language:

1. Do the clever programming with left / right as in the screenshot that inspired you
2. Have separate breeds (eg red-turtles and blue-turtles) for the two scenarios and let them occupy the same world without interacting. If they interact with patches (eg eating grass) then you would need to have a patch variable for each breed (eg red-grass and blue-grass). Create plots and monitors to summarise the aspects of interest. The plots could have both scenarios as different lines, making comparison easy.
3. As for 2, but also have a choose to switch views between breeds (so you could see how they are placed in their world. For example, create an `update-view` button which calls code to show/hide turtles and colour patches according to the choices on a chooser (which might be red, blue and both).
4. Use BehaviorSpace and do the comparison after running the simulations based on the output generated.

All of the options 2-4 have the advantage that they can run more than 2 scenarios (eg red, blue and yellow turtles).

Comment: If you're new to NetLogo and haven't done much programming generally, I STRONGLY recommend that you build a single world version first. You will learn a lot about NetLogo as you do it. You can then build a two-world version with your new knowledge (from scratch) and bring over relevant parts of the code, so you will just be focussing on the two world aspects instead of developing the model. Also, think about whether you genuinely want to see two scenarios at once. You can always run multiple scenarios (see BehaviorSpace tool) and compare your runs from the generated data.

Comment: "Only thing" is not a small task. I had a quick look through. Wherever you have the turtles select from other turtles (eg finding a mate), they have to select only from ones on their side of the wall. One way would be to set up patchsets such as `set left-side patches with [pxcor < 0]` and then do the search like `let partner-to-be one-of turtles-on left-side`. But you have other issues - for example, the point of two worlds is to have two scenarios running with different parameters but your code only sets one lot of parameter values (eg country).

Comment: And just as general advice. When learning NetLogo, start with a simple model, get it to work, and add more detail later. For example, there is no need to generate a random number and use it to select an agent by who value, just use `one-of` like I did in my above comment. Your approach would introduce errors if you had other turtles as there is no guarantee that all the who numbers are turtles of the right type. The tutorial is misleading as it refers to `who` and has all agents (like `ask turtles`) but is just supposed to get you going. There is other documentation and example models.

Comment: So generally, we'll have to make a big overhaul to the code? My task is mainly to just place this whole simulation on the left side ( the first world ), then they'll do the rest.. is that possible with the current code?

Comment: Yes, a big overhaul. Bigger than an SO question.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use [LevelSpace](https://github.com/NetLogo/LevelSpace) (which is based on the Controlling API that Seth Tisue linked in one of the other answers). LevelSpace is a NetLogo extension that allows you to open NetLogo models from inside NetLogo.

Basically what you would want to do here is write a NetLogo model that opens two GUI models from your model file, and sets the variables in each of them as you want.  You would then have a go procedure in the 'parent' model call 'go' in the two child-models, making them run in tandem.

What's cool about LevelSpace is that you can open as many models as you want, and you don't need to code in Java. You just need to use the extension and its primitives.

Disclosure: We're still working on it. It's stable, but the language (primitives) will change over time. Full disclosure: I am one of the authors of the LevelSpace extension, so I am biased. But it will definitely do what you are asking for here.

Edit: Just to show how relatively easy LevelSpace is, this is the entirety of the code required to do what you want. Download the extension, unzip it, put the `ls` folder in your `extensions` folder. Put this code in a separate model, create a setup and a go (repeated) button on its interface, and that's it.:

```
extensions [ls]

to setup
  ls:reset ; resets the levelspace extension
  repeat 2 [ls:load-gui-model "</path/to/your/model.nlogo>"] ; load two of your models
  ls:ask ls:models "setup" ; call 'setup' in all your models
end

to go
  ls:ask ls:models "go"
end
```

If you want to just set up the models without shutting them down and closing the windows, just do

```
to re-setup
  ls:ask ls:models "setup"
end
```

and call the `re-setup` procedure, either with a button or by writing it in the command center.

Comment: You can download the LevelSpace extension here: https://github.com/NetLogo/LevelSpace/releases/tag/0.1

Comment: will it open another world on the side, so we can see it visually?

Comment: It can open with a full interface, like so: http://i.imgur.com/DHdO8ck.png. It can also open headlessly, or with just the view, but in those cases you must interact with the model programmatically.

Comment: something like this ccl.northwestern.edu/modelsim/tools.shtml# "Two-world" modeling

Comment: The "two-worlds" in your link is actually one world, divided up into two worlds. Your model basically has to be coded that way. If you truly want to run two NetLogo worlds independently, but separately from each other, you'll need to run two different instances of NetLogo, probably using the Controlling API or do it with LevelSpace.

Comment: Arthur, thank you. I was able to run it. -- now is there a way where the models don't have to close to be able to run again? Because whenever I press setup, it opens another two -- it's quite a hassle since this will be for an exhibit.

Comment: Absolutely! I edited my answer with the relevant code. Very happy I (and LevelSpace!) could be of help. :)

Comment: By the way - if it's okay for you to share, we always love to hear where people use our software. (The funding bodies that fund our development unsurprisingly do too!) So if you can and don't mind telling us, where will you be doing this exhibit? No pressure, just in case it's okay for you to share. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you keep on asking the same question, I have isolated the bit of my comment that actually gives you the answer.

Wherever you have the turtles select from other turtles (eg finding a mate), they have to select only from ones on their side of the wall. One way would be to set up patchsets such as `set left-side patches with [pxcor < 0]` and then do the search like `let partner-to-be one-of turtles-on left-side`.

If all you want to do is restrict them to one side (say right), then you want xcor > 0 (and xcor < 0 for left side). Use the `abs` function. You will also need to check the position whenever one moves to make sure it stays on its side.

Comment: Jen, really sorry for everything. Just so pressured right now, someone else who actually knows netlogo did my task.. about to get kicked out for not contributing. lol Thank you for your help! -- learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NetLogo's [Controlling API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API) to write a program in Java (or Scala or Clojure or any JVM language you want) that embeds two NetLogo models.